# Prevent fill-paragraph from breaking LaTeX displayed equations in Org Mode

Tags: org-mode, fill-paragraph

In Org Mode `fill-paragraph` brakes the following paragraph (containing LaTeX displayed equation)

```
* Some headline
   Text text text
   \[
   e=mc^2
   \]
   text text text.
```

into

```
* Some headline
  Text text text \[ e=mc^2 \] text text text.
```

so the Org Mode form (with LaTeX preview) no longer reflects the LaTeX layout.

How can I prevent fill-paragraph from breaking LaTeX displayed equations?

---

**UPDATE** (edited on 11.04.2017)

By hacking `org-element.el` file I've modified `org-element-paragraph-separate` variable (in place of its definition). Now it includes also the `"\\\\\\["` regexp, so `\[` is recognized as a place when new paragraph begins. The attempt to modify the `org-element-paragraph-separate` in my init file has failed.

Unfortunately this is only a halfway solution: running `fill-paragraph` with cursor point before `\[` does not break the equation, as expected, but when I run `fill-paragraph` having the cursor after `\[` the paragraph changes to

```
* Some headline
  Text text text
  \[ e=mc^2 \] text text text.
```

Comment: The examples in [(org) LaTeX fragments](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-fragments.html) lists a equation in exactly that inline format and also a longer `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` syntax. The latter isn't modified when I'm calling `fill-paragraph` in the "Text text text" line. I have no LaTeX environment ready to test the inline `\[ e=mc^2 \]` formatting

Comment: @p_wiersig `\[ ... \]` can be compared to `equation*` environment or better to `displaymath` so (in LaTeX) there is a new line after `\[` and `\]` and the equation is centered.

Comment: `\[ ... \]` is so much cleaner in orgmode - I'd like this too.  Having `\[ e=mc^2 \]` on its own dedicated line would be sufficient for me.